# Unable to send mail: Unknown error magento 2.3

Tags: magento2

for me when i want to save the customer's information I got this error **'Unable to send mail: Unknown error'** , this is the method execute

PS : when i change 1 or 2 fields all work fine, but when i make change for 3 fields or more then the error is occurred

[image: magen]

Comment: You need to configure the SMTP for sending email.

Comment: yes you'r right thank you bro